# Need help in finding the count of an unique group of entries in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 3 models Customer, Services and Uses. The Uses model contains the customer_id and service_id(service) used by the customer.

Now what I want is a list of count on the number of times each different service being used by the customer. For example if services say pool and buffet is being used once and twice i want the answer to be [1,2]. I don't want the count on distinct services used rather i want the count on each particular service.

Here are my models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    #other attributes

class Services(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    price = models.IntegerField()

class Uses(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=CASCADE)
    service_id = models.ForeignKey(Services,on_delete=CASCADE)
    time_used = models.TimeField(default=timezone.localtime())
```

This is what I have got which returns the distinct services used.

`count=Uses.objects.filter(customer_id=customer).values('customer_id','service_id').distinct().count()`

Need some help please to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.annotate(…)` the `Services` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Services.objects.filter(
    uses__customer=customer
).annotate(
    times_used=Count('uses')
)
```

The `Services` that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `times_used` that will count the number of times the *`customer`* used that service.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Service` instead of <s>`Services`</s>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know that the django admin appends the models name with an 's' before migrating the models. May you have a nice weekend :)